# How to remove frame attachment

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

```
if (isGameOne == TRUE and isGameTwo == FALSE){
        x.view.frame = xGraph->theGraph.frame;
        y.view.frame = yGraph->theGraph.frame;
    } else {
        /*remove above frame here*/

    }
```

Above is my script i am working with. When `isGameOne` is true, i want it to attach `x.view.frame` to `xGraph->theGraph.frame;` And same for 'y', but this works fine.

What i am having an issue with is understanding how i would remove `x.view.frame` the frame if `isGameOne` is not true (false). 
I am sure its probably something really easy to do, but i am still getting my hand dirty with objective-c. Sorry for my ignorance

Cheers

=========[ How to do this ]========

I actually have a button that quits game one, so inside the `gameOne` method i have

> ```
> if (isGameOne == TRUE and isGameTwo == FALSE){
>         x.view.frame = xGraph->theGraph.frame;
>         y.view.frame = yGraph->theGraph.frame;
>
> }
> ```

inside my `quit` button method i added:

> ```
> isGameTwo = TRUE;
> isGameOne = FALSE;
> if (isGameOne == FALSE and isGameTwo == TRUE) {
>     /* code to remove *DoodlePad from *Grap */
>     [xDoodlePad.view setHidden:YES];
>     [yDoodlePad.view setHidden:YES];
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are doing with those frames. If you want them to be moved to another location on the screen, you could predefine that frame elsewhere and assign it, or you could use CGRectMake to create a specific frame right there.

If you are wanting to hide/show the views based on this condition, you should already have the appropriate frames set before the conditional and just call setHidden on the views with the appropriate argument.

Note that CGRects are structs, so there is assignment of the value itself taking place. You are not maintaining a reference to the other frame.

Comment: the y.view.frame is only comes up when its in game one. it has no use if its not in game one. i'll read the documents on setHidden then. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for teaching me about `isHidden`, it worked like a charm.